# Criando um injector com Google Guice

Tags: java, injeção-de-dependência

Estou tentando utilizar o Google Guice na minha aplicação. Então criei um Modulo fazendo o bind de uma interface com uma implementação...

```
public class ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        super.configure();

        bind(UserDAO.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(UserDAO.class).to(UserDAOImpl.class);

    }

}
```

Mas quando eu vou instanciar o injector utilizando

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationModule());
```

o Google Guice diz que não foi feito o bind...

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for br.com.brunots.training.simple_rest_application.dao.UserDAO was bound.
  Did you mean?
    br.com.brunots.training.simple_rest_application.dao.UserDAO bound  at br.com.brunots.training.simple_rest_application.guice.ApplicationModule.configure(ApplicationModule.java:16)

  at br.com.brunots.training.simple_rest_application.guice.ApplicationModule.configure(ApplicationModule.java:15)

2) A binding to br.com.brunots.training.simple_rest_application.dao.UserDAO was already configured at br.com.brunots.training.simple_rest_application.guice.ApplicationModule.configure(ApplicationModule.java:16).
  at br.com.brunots.training.simple_rest_application.guice.ApplicationModule.configure(ApplicationModule.java:15)
```

O que eu estou fazendo errado?